# Use of Base64 class in JDK7

Tags: java

I am trying to use `Base64` class in JDK 7 but I am getting the error:

> Base64 cannot be resolved

Why does eclipse throw this error?

I am using the code below:

```
byte[] imageData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(readFile(imagePart.getInputStream()));
```

even import statement also shows the same error : `import java.util.Base64;`

Is this class not available in JDK 7?

Comment: Note for Android developers: in Android API 8+, you can use `android.util.Base64` instead of `java.util.Base64`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html):

> Since:
> 1.8

So no, it is not available in JDK 7.

Answer (score 6):

`Base64.getDecoder().decode()` is available from Java 1.8

Try to use **Google Guava**.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <type>jar</type>
   <version>14.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code Snippet**

```
String inputContent = "Hello World";
String base64String = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(inputContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
//decode
System.out.println("Base64:" + base64String);
byte[] contentInBytes = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(base64String);
System.out.println("Source content: " + new String(contentInBytes, "UTF-8"));//Hello World
```

Answer (score 6):

If it is needed to specifically use JDK7 for your project, and you still need to use **java.util.Base64** class, you can include in your project the code for that class from OpenJDK.

Source for this class is available at:
http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Base64.java?av=f

**Base64.java** file can be downloaded at:
http://www.grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Base64.java/?v=source&disposition=attachment

Comment: works like a charm, I only download the font code, paste in my own package, import the propers libraries and done! thanks a lot

Comment: the two links do not work, I found source code on http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Base64.java

Comment: It probably works very well, but the source of the file is distributed as GPLv2 with the classpath exception by Oracle, which mean you'll have to keep it inside a module completely separate from the reste of you code if you want to use that option.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Base64 is available in Java 8 or better

In Java 7 you can use [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

See here for examples http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0598.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated java.util.Base64 is not available until 8.

However I find it worth noting that Android developers have access to android.util.Base64 at language level 7 (API 24) and the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Base64.java) is entirely self contained so you can copy and drop it into your project if you need Base64 and don't want to use a 3rd party like [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/). Just watch rights and usage and all that.